ggplot legend spacing is ignored
I try to insert gaps between the legend entries of a ggplot but the setting legend.spacing.x seems to be ignored. Did I miss anything? (legend.key.spacing works for me - see example)
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_bar(aes(Species, fill = Species), stat = "count") +
  theme(
    legend.key.spacing = unit(20,"points"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(20, "points"),
        )


I am running R 4.4.0 with ggplot2 3.5.1
Can anybody please help?

See this answer, note that it's legend.key.spacing.y. This is a duplicate, say if the post doesn't answer the question and I will reopen.

@RuiBarradas adding the proposed solution guide_legend(byrow = TRUE) does not help (though it works for R 4.3.1 and ggplot 3.4.2).
Maybe it's a bug. I'll report it to ggplot.

legend.key.spacing is a valid argument (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html)

guide_legend is proposed in the accepted answer. With my ggplot2 3.5.1, the same as yours, what worked was the other answer. And though legend.key.spacing is a valid argument, it doesn't do what you ask for.

@RuiBarradas now I got it. I think, I misunderstood several things. First, the ggplot documentation. It was not clear to me that legend.key.spacing is not covering legend.key.spacing.x and .y(as it says Spacing in the horizontal (x) and vertical (y) direction inherit from legend.key.spacing) . And I also misunderstood your first answer. I did not get that you were pointing to another solution than the accepted one. Thanks for the clarification. Now it works.
